# Unable to test Rails route helpers in console when using namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, console

I am setting up the /admin section of a (tennis court booking) site. Routes in **config/routes.rb** are as follows:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :players
  resources :courts
end
```

I am using the usual CRUD controllers, views and _form partials. This is **controllers/admin/court_controller.rb**:

```
class Admin::CourtsController < ApplicationController
  layout "admin"

  def index
    @courts = Court.all
  end

  def show
    @court = Court.find(params[:id])
  end

 def new
    @court = Court.new
 end

 def edit
  @court = Court.find(params[:id])
 end

 ...
end
```

**views/admin/courts/new.html.erb** is standard:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

... and **views/admin/courts/_form.html.erb** starts as follows:

```
<%= form_with(model: @court, local: true, url: admin_court_path(@court)) do |form| %>
```

Everything - including update/PATCH - is working well apart from when I try and create a new court. The route (as usual) is http://localhost:3000/admin/courts/new. I get

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Admin::Courts#new
>   Showing c:/Sites/wtna/app/views/admin/courts/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:
>   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/courts", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
>   Extracted source (around line #1):

```
<%= form_with(model: @court, local: true, url: admin_court_path(@court)) do |form| %>
```

So I jump into the console and try:

> c = Court.new

which displays (as expected):

```
#<Court id: nil, name: nil, active: true, description: nil, address: nil, lat: nil, lng: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, timezone: "Sydney">
```

(I note that the id is nil as I haven't saved the record yet.)

Having said that, when I type:

> app.admin_courts_path OR app.admin_court_path

I get an error:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `admin_court(s)_path' for main:Object

So I have two (related) questions:

1. Why can't I test the routes in the console? (All the usual non-admin routes work perfectly well, eg. app.players_path)
2. What do I need to do to my form helper to get it working?

FWIW, the routes appear to be in order:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you are submitting the form at wrong path. The path you mentioned in `form_with` is *show* path for an existing court record. But you need to submit to */admin/courts* and it should be a POST request.

Try this:

```
form_with(model: @court, local: true, url: admin_courts_path, method: :post)
```

Read more [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Your second suggestion doesn't work as it generates this error: "undefined method `courts_path'". It seems the controller is ignoring the namespace and looking for the default (public) path to the courts. Your first suggestion works - yes, you're right about the plural being the correct convention - but then breaks the form for the update/PATCH action - the form is displayed but doesn't save. I get the feeling - unlike non-namespaced routes - that I'm not going to be able to use the same form partial for create and update. What do you think?

Comment: It makes sense that it doesn't understand the namespace _admin_ correctly. We never mentioned it in the form helper. Use the first approach.

Comment: And for edit to work, you can extract all the form fields to a partial and render them under two different `form_with`(s). One for new court and another for edit court.

Comment: Thanks, @Jagdeep Singh. I've done that and it works. Any suggestions for my first question?

Comment: Try running `admin_courts_path` in the console.

Comment: As before: "NameError: undefined local variable or method `admin_courts_path' for main:Object"

Comment: FWIW, I can now successfully run "app.admin_courts_path" in the local Rails console. I assume either a restart or code change has affected this.